# Shape operator of surface of revolution w.r.t. to coordinate vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

I have a problem with the computation of the shape operator of a surface of revolution
$f(u,v)=(\gamma_1(u) \cos(v), \gamma_2(u) \sin(v), \gamma_2(u))$, where $\gamma(u)=(\gamma_1(u),\gamma_2(u))$ is a an arclength-parametrized curve such that $\gamma_1(u)>0$.

I am using the following definitions

[image]

[image]

The shape operator is the smooth endomorphism field $A$ satisfying

$$
dN(X)=df(AX)
$$

where $X \in TM$ with $TM$ denoting the tangent bundle of M. Here is my attempt at a solution. Let $p=(u,v) \in M$. The Jacobi matrix of $f$ at $p$ is given by

$$
f'(p)=
\begin{pmatrix}
 \gamma_1'(u) \cos(v) & -\gamma_1(u) \sin(v) \\
 \gamma_1'(u) \sin(v) & \gamma_1(u) \cos(v)  \\
 \gamma_2'(u)         &         0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The unit normal is given by

$$
N=\frac{f_u \times f_v }{|f_u \times f_v |}
=\frac{1}{\gamma_1(u)} 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -\gamma_2'(u) \gamma_1(u) \cos(v) \\
  -\gamma_2'(u) \gamma_1(u) \sin(v) \\
  \gamma_1'(u) \gamma_1(u)  
 \end{pmatrix} 
=\begin{pmatrix}
  -\gamma_2'(u) \cos(v) \\
  -\gamma_2'(u) \sin(v) \\
  \gamma_1'(u)    
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Then the Jacobi matrix of $N$ at $p$ is given by

$$
N'(p)=
\begin{pmatrix}
 -\gamma_2''(u) \cos(v) & \gamma_2'(u) \sin(v)  \\
 -\gamma_2''(u) \sin(v) & -\gamma_2'(u) \cos(v) \\
 \gamma_1''(u)          &           0  
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Consider the coordinate vectorfields

$$
U: M \to TM , U(p)=(p,e_1) \\
V: M \to TM , V(p)=(p,e_2). 
$$.

Let $S=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ be the matrix representation of $A$. Then

$$
AU=aU+cV \\
AV=bU+dV.
$$

Using the definition of $A$ we get $dN(U)=df(AU)$. With $dN(U)=N'(p) e_1, df(U)=f'(p)e_1, df(V)=f'(p) e_2$ and the linearity of $df$ we get

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 -\gamma_2''(u) \cos(v) \\
 -\gamma_2''(u) \sin(v) \\
  \gamma_1''(u)
\end{pmatrix}
=a 
\begin{pmatrix}
 \gamma_1'(u) \cos(v) \\
 \gamma_1'(u) \sin(v) \\
 \gamma_2'(u)         
\end{pmatrix}
+
c
\begin{pmatrix}
 -\gamma_1(u) \sin(v) \\
 \gamma_1(u) \cos(v)  \\
          0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Analogously, using $V$ instead of $U$ we get

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 \gamma_2'(u) \sin(v)  \\
 -\gamma_2'(u) \cos(v) \\
            0  
\end{pmatrix}
=b 
\begin{pmatrix}
 \gamma_1'(u) \cos(v) \\
 \gamma_1'(u) \sin(v) \\
 \gamma_2'(u)         
\end{pmatrix}
+
d
\begin{pmatrix}
 -\gamma_1(u) \sin(v) \\
 \gamma_1(u) \cos(v)  \\
          0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

In total we get 6 equations

$$
-\gamma_2''(u) \cos(v)=a \gamma_1'(u) \cos(v)-c\gamma_1(u) \sin(v)  \tag{1}
$$

$$     
-\gamma_2''(u) \sin(v)=a \gamma_1'(u) \sin(v)+c \gamma_1(u) \cos(v) \tag{2}
$$

$$
\gamma_1''(u)=a \gamma_2'(u)                                        \tag{3}
$$

$$
\gamma_2'(u) \sin(v)=b \gamma_1'(u) \cos(v)-d \gamma_1(u) \sin(v) \tag{4}
$$

$$
-\gamma_2'(u) \cos(v)=b \gamma_1'(u) \sin(v)+d\gamma_1(u) \cos(v) \tag{5} 
$$

$$
0=b \gamma_2'(u)                                                  \tag{6}
$$

Adding (1) to (2) yields

$$
-\gamma_2''(u) (\cos(v)+\sin(v))=a \gamma_1'(u) (\cos(v)+\sin(v))+c \gamma_1(u) (\cos(v)-\sin(v)).
$$

This implies $c=0$. So we have the equation

$$
-\gamma_2''(u)=a \gamma_1'(u). \tag{7}
$$

Dividing (1) by $\cos(v)$ and adding the resulting equation to (7) yields

$$
\gamma_1''(u)-\gamma_2''(u)=a(\gamma_1'(u)+\gamma_2'(u)). 
$$

Dividing by $(\gamma_1'(u)+\gamma_2'(u))$ and using the identity $1=\frac{(\gamma_1'(u)-\gamma_2'(u))}{(\gamma_1'(u)-\gamma_2'(u))}$ on the left-hand side yields

$$
a=\frac{-\gamma_2''(u) \gamma_1'(u)-\gamma_1''(u) \gamma_2'(u)}{(\gamma_1'(u))^2-(\gamma_2'(u))^2}.
$$

Moreover (4) and (6) imply $b=0, d=-\frac{\gamma_2'(u)}{\gamma_1(u)}$. So the matrix representation of $A$ is given by

$$
S=
\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{-\gamma_2''(u) \gamma_1'(u)-\gamma_1''(u) \gamma_2'(u)}{(\gamma_1'(u))^2-    (\gamma_2'(u))^2} 
 & 0 \\
 0   
 & -\frac{\gamma_2'(u)}{\gamma_1(u)}. 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

However according to [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3281840/computing-the-weingarten-map-shape-operator) this result is not correct. According to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_surfaces#Surfaces_of_revolution) I seem to have found the correct normal vector. This suggests that there must be an error in my subsequent computations but so far I have not been able to find any. Why does my approach not work?